# Run-python problem Emacs + Anaconda (virtualenv)

Tags: python

When I used run-python through 'c-c c-p', I got the messages like below.
I don't know what it is.

Anaconda within GNU emacs in Mac.
It doesn't seem like a problem, just came out.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, there's same problem. If you have any similar issue, you need to check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33726268/emacs-inferior-python-shell-shows-the-send-message-with-each-python-shell-send-r

Comment: @sehwan-yoo's link is good.  The message there, I think, is to try using a Python with GNU readline rather than libedit.  You can tell which one you have with `import readline; readline.__doc__` and make sure it says "readline" and not "libedit" in the docstring.